# php code send notification to all devices GCM

Tags: php

I need a little help to send notification to all devices at once.
I know array need to be used for that but can't get the idea. A little hint will also work

```
DB table design
id    gcm_regid   name  email   created_at
```

Currently i have to fill out the form for all the devices and send notification one by one.

PHP code:

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });
        function sendPushNotification(id){
            var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
            $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_message.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      $('.txt_message').val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="devices">
            <?php
            if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                ?>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                            <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="send_container">
                                <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                <?php }
            } else { ?>
                <li>
                    No Users Registered Yet!
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

send_message.php

```
  <?php
 if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
$regId = $_GET["regId"];
$message = $_GET["message"];

include_once './GCM.php';

$gcm = new GCM();

$registatoin_ids = array($regId);
$message = array("price" => $message);

$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

echo $result;
}
?>
```

EDIT: Or can anyone tell me how do i use checkbox for select all "id"s?

Comment: Can you please make your question a bit clear? and where is your send_message.php script?

Comment: Well i actually want to send common message to all devices. Currently the above code gives me seperate forms for each device. I just want a common form and it should send the message to all the devices rather than me copy pasting the message and then sending.